# How to test new SD card in Windows?

Tags: windows, sd-card

I purchased a new microSD card and I basically want to test it to ensure it's not corrupted and it's speed is within the specification printed on the packing (Class 10).

How can I do that?

Comment: Copy files equal to the capacity of it and see how long it takes, or run some sort of drive benchmark software across it.

Comment: Asking "*What is the easiest way*" is not a good format for this site because "*...answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise*". This is per the site guidelines about [closed questions](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: 1) it is not "spamming", it is a comment. 2) because you would learn to expect others to correct your mistakes. 3) I didn't down vote your question. 4) instead of making inflammatory assumptions, don't take it so personal. My comment was to help you improve this and future questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to test for corruption, try the free ChkFlsh. It's a lot like HDTune but for memory cards.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using CrystalDiskMark - saw it being used by lots of people who posted screenshots of benchmark they ran. Here is the website from which you can download it, it's free:

[Crystal Disk Mark & Info download](http://crystalmark.info/download/index-e.html)